# jQuery, HTML table and .last()

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am reading a book about jQuery and HTML, and there is something I can't understand, and after an hour and a half searching, I can't find the answer on the web, so I'll ask here directly. So I have a table on my page:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</th>
    <th>Courriel</th>
    <th>Compagnie</th>
    <td>Dernier contact</td>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>William Smith</td>
      <td>(555) 642-7371</td>
      <td>william@testing.com</td>
      <td>Acme Industries</td>
      <td>
        <time datetime="2014-10-21">2014-10-21</time>
        <div class="overlay">These are my notes for William</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob Morris</td>
      <td>(555) 748-4465</td>
      <td>Bob@moretesting.com</td>
      <td>ABC Corp</td>
      <td>
        <time datetime="2015/01/01">2015/01/01</time>
        <div class="overlay">Notes pour Bob</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ted Mosus</td>
      <td>(555) 484-9835</td>
      <td>Ted@SomeEmail.com</td>
      <td>Tada Inc.</td>
      <td>
        <time datetime="2016/05/21">2016/05/21</time>
        <div class="overlay">Ne pas appeler avant 10:00 AM</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yvan Doc</td>
      <td>(555) 258-7946</td>
      <td>yvan@doc.com</td>
      <td>ABC Corp</td>
      <td>
        <time datetime="2015/07/18">2015/07/18</time>
        <div class="overlay">Non non ce n'est pas un docteur!</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">4 contacts displayed</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <caption>Contact des ventes</caption>
</table>
```

and when I go on the console in Chrome, I type in the following command

```
$('time').siblings('.overlay').parents('tr').last();
```

Now I would expect that it would return me the row 'Yvan Doc' which is the last line in my table, but no, it returns the 'William Smith' line, and when I change .last() for .first(), it returns me 'Yvan Doc' instead of 'William Smith'.

Can someone explain to me why the table seems to be inverted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause actually lies with `.parents()` not `.last()`. If you read the docs for [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) it states (emphasis mine):

> When multiple DOM elements are in the original set, **the resulting set
>   will be in reverse order of the original elements** as well, with
>   duplicates removed.

You might be more interested in using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), which when used like `$('time').siblings('.overlay').closest('tr').last()` will return the Yvan Doc row.

Comment: Ah... I was looking at the .last() documentation... that explains it, thanks for the answer!

Comment: $('table').children('tbody').children().last()  will return the Yvan Doc row too.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to comment as the what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.closest()` with `.find()` and `.first()`:

```
$('time').closest('tbody').find('tr').first();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that you're starting with a multi-selector (selecting all elements with the 'time' tag), then getting all their siblings, then getting all their parents and then trying to find the last.  Your code is trying to find a single item while working with selectors that are returning multiple elements.

You should just grab the `<tbody>` element and and get it's last child `<tr>` using:

```
$('tbody tr').last();
```

If you have more than one `<tbody>` on your page, give it a unique ID and access it like this:

```
$('#tbody-name:last-child');
```

Comment: There should be a space between selectors. But that would be wrong target.

Comment: That works, but unfortunately it didn't explain it. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I edited my comment.  Using an ID and selecting 'last-child' would be the most memory efficient way of doing this, and the most succinct, imo, but the ballots have been cast.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info in your post, it works and it is a great help, however I was trying to understand the why it was working this way, as I am training by reading the code. You post was still helpful!

Comment: No problem.  I know what your code is trying to do, but I can't explain exactly why your process results in getting the 'Yvan' instead of 'Will' `<tr>`, but I do know it has to do with telling multiple elements to target a single element at the same time.  Imo, it never hurts to put a class or ID on elements.  Helps isolate your code better for DOM access or manipulation and avoids possible errors of unintentionally selecting multiple DOM elements when you were trying to focus on just one.  Also, the less method chaining and traversal, the better, as far as memory usage goes.